# Blazor Web Assembly connecting to OAuth via Implicit Flow

Tags: oauth, blazor, webassembly, blazor-webassembly, implicit-flow

In my blazor web assembly project, I have to connect to a Web API that doesn't implement OIDC.

I read on the aspnetcore github thet they made the choice to implement only OIDC connections...

I think I have to write a custom implementation of `RemoteAuthenticationService` and add it via the `builder.Services.AddRemoteAuthentication` method, but can't understand how to do this.
Reading the current implementation of `RemoteAuthenticationService` doesn't help.

The only thing I have to do to connect the Web API is to call this URI :

```
https://<webapi>/oauth/Authorize?client_id=<MyClientId>&state=<State>&scope=read&response_type=token&redirect_uri=<RedirectUri>
```

The user fill in the form and get redirected in my blazor app via the RedirectUri, having the accessToken in url parameters.

Then I have to add the accessToken in the headers of all Web API Requests, but I found how to do it via `AuthorizationMessageHandler`.

How can I implement this flow with Blazor Web Assembly ? Do I search in wrong direction ?

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing - Blazor WebAssembly app against an existing OAuth server either via implicit or authorization code grant. Did you have any luck finding a solution?